# calculate total value instead of rows using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to calculate the total number of tokens collected instead of the number of records in the mysql db. Although I have already put the SUM function in the query but it still counts the no. of rows.

```
<?php 
   $conn = mysqli_connect(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

   $query = " SELECT SUM(nooftokensused) FROM bidding WHERE biddedon >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-01-01') GROUP BY biddingid";
   $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run); 

   echo '<h1>'.$row.'</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: Can you please show us some example data and the result that you see?

Comment: Why would you think there is a difference between total rows and SUM(nooftokensused) ?

Comment: It's strange that you don't care which total belongs to which biddingid

Comment: basically im trying to calculate the total nooftokensused for each month. So for each row the nooftokens varies and i want to sum up the total value instead of the rows

Comment: ...for each biddingid

Answer (score 0):

I have added comments with my code.  Also, you are using `mysqli_connect(server, dbuser, dbpw, db)` , you have not declared them as variables with `$` symbol.

```
<?php
    //Make connection with DB
    $con = mysqli_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpw, $db);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT SUM(nooftokensused) as summ FROM bidding WHERE biddedon >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-01-01') GROUP BY biddingid";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        // Associative array
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo $row["summ"];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 0;
    }
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead of mysqli_num_rows().

```
<?php 
                $conn = mysqli_connect(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

                $query = " SELECT SUM(value_sum) AS nooftokensused FROM bidding WHERE biddedon >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-01-01') GROUP BY biddingid";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run); 

                echo '<h1>'.$row['nooftokensused'].'</h1>';
 ?>
```

Comment: this error msg pops out:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in